# How do I enable WiFi on my Acer Aspire 5710Z?

Tags: wireless, keyboard-layout, acer, bios

I have Ubuntu 12.4LTS

I find that the Internet works well when hard wired, but not through my WiFi.

I have tried additional hardware and update manager and everything up to date.

The <kbd>F3</kbd> button doesn't work, and none of my laptops hard keys above the keyboard work (including WiFi, obviously, amoung, mail, bluetooth and saturn)

I found a forum where I enabled WiFi through a terminal session but it disconnected me from the hard wired connection, and for the first time the WiFi signal came up. It showed it was searching (flashing up to down) and searching for approx 30 seconds then it disappeared and turned the hard wired internet back on.

So, a glimmer of hope. To me it feels like Ubuntu is turning on WiFi, but the computer doesn't have it running.

Help please!  P.S I can't find anywhere in the BIOS where I can play with networking settings.   Someone will have to walk me through that if you think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo rfkill list all`

above will list status of your wireless card. If it's blocked you can do a

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

if this doesn't work then check your wireless card by typing following in terminal

```
sudo lspci -nnk
```

and search for something like Wireless LAN
 then check for it's compatibility and alternative drivers to make it work.

Even if it's not compatible there are ways to make it work like you can use windows drivers with
**ndiswrapper** but it's less likely you will need that

Comment: Thanks for replying amigo,

rfkill unblocked it but it was alreadz unblocked.

Your sudo command does not work for me. do i type it specifically as you wrote it *lspci -nnk*    ?

so ndiswrapper?   i downloading it exported it and following instructions in terminal it cant find anything.. @user2007060

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/152104/user2007060

Answer (score 1):

You should check if Secure Boot is enabled and, if so, disable it.

I spent at least 3 hours with the same problem until I realized secure boot was enabled by default in my laptop's BIOS. I turned it off and WiFi *instantly* worked fine.